# In a $C^*$-algebra, why is the norm of a positive element attained by a positive, linear functional of norm 1?

Tags: functional-analysis

By Hahn-Banach it holds in any Banach space that the norm of a positive element attained by a functional of norm $1$. But why is it true in a $C^*$-algebra that norm of any positive element is attained by a positive, linear functional of norm $1$?

Comment: Is that true? If you take a negative element (with positive norm), then any positive functional must map it to a negative number, i.e. not its norm.

Comment: Right, I meant positive elements.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, with $a\in A$ positive, and let $B$ be the $C^*$-subalgebra of $\tilde A$ generated by $1$ and $a$.  Then there is a character $\tau_0$ on $B$ such that $\tau_0(a)=\|a\|$.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem, $\tau_0$ extends to a linear functional $\tau_1$ on $\tilde A$ of norm $1$, and since $\tau_1(1)=\tau_0(1)=1$, it is positive.  The restriction $\tau$ of $\tau_1$ to $A$ is a positive linear functional of norm $1$, and $\tau(a)=\|a\|$.